# Add custom domain in own project

Tags: next.js, dns, vercel, custom-domain

I am building a next js project and deployment on vercel. User can **add custom domain** but for now i am **assigning sub domain against username**

I am confusing how custom domain logic build. Like two users add same domain abc.com and i added this domain in vercel and vercel send me dns configuration

Now i want to know which user configured dns because vercel automatically detect domain connected on domain configuration

User details exist on each domain in database

Comment: Could you specify what exactly didn't work as supposed?

Comment: @HoRn in saas products, two users add same domain and i send a record to both user, now one of user is configured, vercel automatically detect and connected to domain. But how i update in backend that which user configured